# What is the Nuget repositories.config file for?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

What is the file `packages/repositories.config`? Should it be kept under version control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NuGet - repositories.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286261/nuget-repositories-config)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to Nuget dev David Ebbo

> If you use the Package Restore workflow, you can completely omit the Packages folder from source control (including this file).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7297465/284795

Comment: Note to not confuse SolutionFolder/packages/repositories.config with ProjectName/packages.config... While the former can be omitted (per the comment above), I don't think the latter should be?

Comment: @Funka they don't even have the same name.. ?

Comment: You're right, technically the file names aren't the same but the "packages" folder name is, hence the note. So instead of adding a question mark at the end of my comment, I should have ended instead with "be sure not to confuse these two different things since their names are similar", especially since when in a source control commit dialog they might be easily mistaken for one another.

Comment: With NuGet 2.7, a new Automatic Package Restore approach has been introduced. This page also covers 'Using NuGet without committing packages to source control': http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/msbuild-integrated

Answer (score 13):

If you open it in a text editor, you will see it is a list of all of the `packages.config` files for your solution.

Should it be kept under version control?  That depends.  NuGet's built in package restore feature will recreate this file because it uses the `packages.config` file for each project when that project is built.  However, TeamCity's package restore feature uses `packages/repositories.config`.

Why would you use the TeamCity package restore if you have NuGet's package restore enabled?  If you have a Silverlight project with NuGet packages, for some reason something goes wrong with the package restore when building with MSBuild.  For more details, check my question on the issue.  [Issue with PackageRestore, Silverlight, and MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435938/issue-with-packagerestore-silverlight-and-msbuild)